# How to parse an URI with a custom scheme?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, uri

I need to parse URIs with custom schemes not (yet) implemented by the .NET framework such as "sip://" and "rtsp://". I already tried extending the `GenericUriParser` class, but boy, I've never seen such a horrible class to work with and I ended giving up with no luck.

Are there any other ways to parse an URI? Using regular expressions? Are those any good for more than checking if an URI is valid, like splitting up the URI to its fragments (scheme, path, <strike>query</strike>)?

Comment: Potential help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847/regex-to-validate-uris

Comment: This SO question is related to RTSP URI parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12036958/363573